# Getting an additional "0" after for loop

Tags: c++

I'm currently doing a program based around structures and arrays with structures, while I've understood most of it I recently ran into an issue I cannot figure out. At one point in my code I do a for loop inside a for loop in order to display a series of four numbers, however at the end of displaying these four numbers the next line begins with a 0, followed by the rest of my data.

I'll point out the part I'm talking about.
I use a text document called "Student Data.txt", its contents are...

> Amy Adams
>   10111
>   97 86 78 95
>   Ben Barr
>   20222
>   89 81 73 87
>   Carla Carr
>   30333
>   79 71 63 77
>   Don Davis
>   40444
>   69 62 58 67
>   Edna Eaton
>   50555
>   63 51 62 48

My output is...

> Amy Adams
>   10111
>   97 86 78 95
>   0Ben Barr
>   20222
>   89 81 73 87
>   0Carla Carr
>   30333
>   79 71 63 77
>   0Don Davis
>   40444
>   69 62 58 67
>   0Edna Eaton
>   50555
>   63 51 62 48
>   0Press any key to continue . . .

*header.h*

```
//libraries
using namespace std;
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>

//import
ifstream inFile("Student Data.txt");

//declarations and structures
const int gSIZE = 4;
const int sSIZE = 5;
struct gRec {
    string name;
    int studID;
    int grades[gSIZE];
    int avgscore;
    char lettergrade;
} students[sSIZE];

int printrecord(gRec record);
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{

    for (int k = 0; k != 5; k++)
    {
        string str;
        getline(inFile, students[k].name);
        inFile >> students[k].studID;
        for (int i = 0; i != 4; i++)            <-------Here is the problematic for loop
        {
            inFile >> students[k].grades[i];
        }
        getline(inFile, str);
        cout << printrecord(students[k]);
    }

    system("pause");
}

int printrecord(gRec record)
{
    cout << record.name << endl;
    cout << record.studID << endl;
    //for (int n = 0; n != 4; n++)      
    //record.grades[n];
    cout << record.grades[0] << " ";
    cout << record.grades[1] << " ";
    cout << record.grades[2] << " ";
    cout << record.grades[3];
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you consider stepping through your code with a decent debugger before asking this question here? We require you should have done so to ask valid questions (dumping code isn't enough).

Comment: Apologies, im as new as they come when it pertains to computers and coding; not all too much experience with debuggers or anything of the sort, but I will try to do more research in the future.

Comment: _"I will try to do more research in the future."_ You really should, if you really want to contribute to, or gain results from the site in future (answering/asking). The question/answer ban detection automatisms of the site are pretty strict meanwhile. You even should try to improve this actual question, to avoid more down-/close-votes that will lead to ban you from participation.

Comment: I can't do much more to improve this question, I included all the coding I have currently and most of it is probably written pretty badly. I figured then that deleting this might be the best course of action since its causing people quite a mischief it seems, however it wouldn't let me.  
  
I'll reframe from using this site in the future, sorry to anger you.

Comment: You didn't really _anger_ me (that actually sounds quite different). I'm just trying to teach you how to use this site, and how you can continue using it. There are ways to improve your question (I well know you can't delete it, and no that's not the most appropriate action expected). Be sure reading all of [these articles](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) thoroughly, to find possible ways to improve your quesiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line:

```
cout << printrecord(students[k]);
```

with

```
printrecord(students[k]);
```

The first one prints out the value the function returns, 0 in your case.

In fact your print function actually doesn't need a return value so you should probably change its signature to

```
void printrecord(gRec record)
```

and remove the return statement at the end.

Comment: Wow, this not only solved the main problem, but it also solved a couple of other issues as well, thanks man.